# How to decrement a character value alphabetically in C++

Tags: c++

Is there a way to decrement a character value alphabetically in C++?

For example, changing a variable containing
`'b'` to the value `'a'` or a variable containing
`'d'` to the value `'c'` ?

I tried looking at character sequence but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: what is the result of aaaa ?

Comment: You are aware that `'a'` is the same as 97, and `'b'` is 98?

Comment: is this meant to be hexadecimal notation or what. what should the result be of going down from `aaaa`

Comment: Code would be good, to clarify the question. Short answer is yes, `'c' - 1 == 'b'`

Comment: i dont understand the downvoting... this is a normal question

Comment: Agreed. It does not seem to be worded in clear way when you understand character representation, but if the asking user understood this then why would he ask this question? In the c++ community we frequently forget others are often learning c++ from a much higher level language / more casual environment and might not know things we consider low-level basics.

Comment: @lifeOfPI Didn't downvote, but generally downvotes like this are best avoided by providing a code snippet, like simply: `string s1 = "abcd"; string s2 = ???; cout << s2 << endl; /* should print abcc */`. Especially the original version of question was very vague, talking about characters, showing strings and not explaining what exactly they are (C++ has many kinds of strings and characters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Characters are essentially one byte integers (although the representation may vary between compilers). While there are many  encodings which map integer values to characters, almost all of them map `'a'` to `'z'` characters in successive numerical order. So, if you wanted to change the string `"aaab"` to `"aaaa"` you could do something like the following:

```
char letters [4] = {'a','a','a','b'};
letters[3]--;
```

Comment: `char` is its own type, signed/unsigned is compiler specific, and quite often it is signed.

Comment: You are correct good sir. I updated the answer to be more accurate. +1

Answer (score 0):

Alphabet characters are part of the ASCII character table.  65 is uppercase letter A, and 32 bits later, which is 97, is lowercase letter A.  Letters B through Z and b through z are 66 through 90 and 98 through 122, respectively)  The original computer programmers made it 32 bits apart in the ASCII chart rather than 26 (letters in the alphabet) because bit manipulation can be done to either easily change from lowercase to uppercase (and vice-versa), as well as ignoring the case (by ignoring the 32 bit - 0010 0000).

This way, for example, the 84th character on the ASCII chart, which represents the letter T, is represented with the bits 0101 0100.  Lowercase t is 116 which is 0111 0100.  When ignoring the case, the 1 in the 32 bit (6th position from the right) is ignored.  You can see all the other bits are exactly the same for uppercase and lowercase.  This makes it more convenient for everyone and more optimal for the computer.

To decrement just convert the character to its ASCII character value, decrement by 1, then take that integer and convert it back into ASCII value.  Be careful when you have an 'A' though (or 'a'), as that's a special case.

Comment: Note, this only applies to English alphabet and ASCII text. Most actual text handled by applications is something else, increasingly some UTF, so for a real-world application things get a *lot* more hairy.